# Optimizing nested while loops in awk to avoid seg faults and core dumping

Tags: bash, awk, segmentation-fault

I am using nested while loops in awk and it is using up large amounts of processing power and in some cases having seg faults and core dumps.

An example line of input:

> 2846196
>   TGGTGTATTTGAGGAAGTGTAGTGGGGTATGGTGGTGTTAGAGGGTGGGGATATGGAGGCGGTATAAGGTTAAGGCGTCGGGGGATGGTTAGAGGGAAGTAACGGTCGCGTTTGTG
>   0C2C1C2C10C2C4C4C4C13C10C1C4C0C6C10C0C15C4C5

each line has 3 tab separated entries: a number, then a string, then a list of which letter to replace and with what. so you go 0 letters replace with a C then go 2 letters and replace the next etc..

Here is my code:

```
awk     -v OFS="\t" '   
{nREAD=split($2,READ,""); 
nCs=split($3,Cs, "[ACGT]");
printf $1"\t"$2"\t";
sum=0;
j=1;
while (j<=nCs){ i=0; while (i<Cs[j]) {i++; printf READ[i+sum]}; sum=sum+i+1; j++; printf "G"};
printf "\n"
}
' tempGA.sam > tempGA.results
```

The error I get, which I believe is related to running out of ram:

./%methylReadsNovoalign.sh: line 73:   899 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)

or

./%methylReadsNovoalign.sh: line 73:   642 Killed

./%methylReadsNovoalign.sh: line 73:   475 Killed

The core report files were also 90+ GB while processing files that were less than 5 GB, which seems like a lot.

Is there anything in my while loop that would be using so much memory?
This is inside of a while loop in a larger bash script, but only some of the awk processes crash. Will it be trying to do things in parallel or do I manually need to clear some of the memory during my while loop? I don't get how it is using so much memory. All of the strings should be 125 characters long.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: format your sample input to be as you describe it to be, add the expected output given that input, and format your code to be legible. If your real data has more than 1 line of input then show more than 1 line of input in your question. Have you tried adding debugging print statements in the obvious places in your code? What did they tell you?

Comment: Also - those error messages are about lines in your shell script. Are you SURE it's the awk script that's using a lot of memory and you're not loading up shell arrays or dividing by zero or something elsewhere in your script? Post a [mcve] so we can see a complete script that exhibits the problem you want help with.

Comment: 1.) Further to @EdMorton's point, there's a space in the sample input that should evidently be a tab. 2.)  Likewise, you evidently meant IFS rather than OFS. 3.) There's nothing in the awk program that uses much memory, but it might be worthwhile running it against one (or maybe even all) of the input files, just in case there's something wrong with the input.  4.) My guess is that it's the shell script that's the problem.

Comment: Something to check is that your file has the expected line endings. Sometimes awk sees the entire file as one huge line and this can cause it to crash.

Comment: @jas awk would only see the entire file as one huge line if the entire file actually **WAS** one huge line.

Comment: Good point, @EdMorton :)  The specific example that's bitten me in the past (showing my age, here) is exporting CSV from Excel on Mac and ending up with a file that uses only CR (0x0d) for line endings. From awk's point of view as well as other *nix utilities, there was only one line.

Comment: @jas ah, I see. According to POSIX a text file contains text lines and a text line ends in `\n` so what you're describing isn't even a text file per POSIX and so YMMV with running any UNIX text-processing tool on that.

Comment: After scanning through the input files I found the problem. Some of my inputs had "^" inserted into them for some reason and when I split the numbers from the letters the "^" got included as part of the number so it was trying to print outside of the array. Thanks for all of the help.